# C# Regex Capture Substring Without Whitespace

Tags: c#, regex

I parse simple json object:

```
{"phone":"8 920 034-00-88"}
```

To get phone number i use code below:

```
string phoneStr = @"{""phone"":""8 920 034-00-88""}";
string searchPattern = @"{\s*""phone""\s*:\s*""(?<phone>.+)""\s*}";

Match match = Regex.Match(phoneStr, searchPattern);
if (match.Success)
   Console.WriteLine("Phone number:{0}", match.Groups["phone"].Value);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Phone number did not match");
```

I get result like: '8 920 034-00-88', but i need only digit symbol in phone number without whitespace and '-' like: '89200340088'.
Can i get this result use only Regex?

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use a JSON parser.

Comment: `var digits = new string("{\"phone\":\"8 920 034-00-88\"}".Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex.Replace and replace everything that isn't a digit:

```
var result = new Regex(@"\D").Replace(phoneStr, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove whitespaces, hyphens and apostrophes

```
var value = Regex.Replace("8 920 034 - 00 - 88", @"\s|\-|'", "");
```

> Result: value = 89200340088

Comment: Replace any non-digit is far safer, as long as you want any kind of padding removed. Some places use `/` as separator as well, there's no end to the delimiters.